# How can I use ImageJ as a library for a separate Java application?

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

In a regular Java application, I have a BufferedImage that I would like to manipulate with ImageJ. I have a macro that is exactly what I need to execute. I suspect that the first step is to make an ImagePlus object, but I am not sure how to then run a macro on the ImagePlus object from within Java. Section 7.3 of the ImageJ tutorial found [here](http://www.imagingbook.com/fileadmin/goodies/ijtutorial/tutorial171.pdf) says:

> If you decide to use ImagePlus as your internal image format you can also use all plugins
>   and macros from the ImageJ distribution as well as all other ImageJ plugins.

But does not indicate how to do so. If someone could explain how, or point me towards a resource that does, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following site describes ImageJ API with examples: http://albert.rierol.net/imagej_programming_tutorials.html#ImageJ programming basics

The examples include reading images, processing pixels etc. Well, I guess you will also need to use the [API documentation](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html) a lot.

Comment: This is perfect! `IJ.run` is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a sample code that opens an image, inverts it and saves it back:

```
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.io.FileSaver;
import ij.process.ImageProcessor;

ImagePlus imgPlus = new ImagePlus("path-to-sample.jpg");
ImageProcessor imgProcessor = imgPlus.getProcessor();
imgProcessor.invert();
FileSaver fs = new FileSaver(imgPlus);
fs.saveAsJpeg("path-to-inverted.jpg");
```

And here's a sample code that shows how to manipulate an image to make it grayscale:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = imgProcessor.getBufferedImage();
for(int y=0;y<bufferedImage.getHeight();y++)
{
    for(int x=0;x<bufferedImage.getWidth();x++)
    {
        Color color = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y));
        int grayLevel = (color.getRed() + color.getGreen() + color.getBlue()) / 3;
        int r = grayLevel;
        int g = grayLevel;
        int b = grayLevel;
        int rgb = (r<<16)  | (g<<8)  | b;
        bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
    }
}
ImagePlus grayImg = new ImagePlus("gray", bufferedImage);
fs = new FileSaver(grayImg);
fs.saveAsJpeg("path-to-gray.jpg");
```

I hope it helps you get started :)

Comment: Would this be applicable for PNG also? or other image formats?

Comment: I found these examples while looking for grayscale conversion. This grayscale conversion could also be done directly using the `ImageConverter` and replacing the two ImageProcessor lines from the first example with `ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter(imgPlus)` and then `converter.convertToGray8();`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an opensource project implementation with imagej for photo sharing web app.

Use this as a reference to implement imagej apis in your application

http://www.gingercart.com/Home/java-snippets/create-image-thumbnail-in-java-using-imagej-api